# Jenkins: How does it look up for Jenkinsfile location

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've created I `Jenkinsfile` into my really straightforward repository:

```
├── Jenkinsfile
└── README.md
```

My question is: How this file is processed by Jenkins?

I mean, how does jenkins know that has to pick up the `Jenkinsfile` located on wherever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create Pipeline type Job in Jenkins it gives you two options in "Pipeline Definition". Choose "Pipeline script from SCM". Here you can define repository location (git) and "Script Path" - path to your Jenkinsfile in the repository

Comment: In the new Jenkins 2.4, you have to make a Pipeline project. 
Then, Configure->Pipeline, you'll find the options mentioned in the answer